# Are same date values with different formats in SAS the same?

Tags: sas

Same date in different format returning different values. Hence comparison is not matching.

```
else if (input(cmp_date,date10.) ne input(Completion_Date,date9.) ) then cmp_missmatch_Flag='Mismatch in treatment Completion Date';
    end;
```

cmp_date is a character value (format: 09/29/2020) and Completion_Date is a numeric date value (format: 29SEP2020) in the original dataset. But they don't match each other when comparing if I remove the 'input ' function for 'Completion_Date'. Can anybody help explain this? Thank you.

Comment: If you check, your first argument is empty because you used the wrong informat.  You need to use the appropriate informat that matches your data then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format attached to a variable does not change the value.  But you only have one variable that has date values. If COMPLETION_DATE is numeric with the DATE9. format attached the values are date values.  If COMP_DATE is a character string with values that look like MM/DD/YYYY then you can use the MMDDYY informat to read the strings into date values.

```
if ( input(cmp_date,mmddyy10.) ne Completion_Date ) then ...
```

It is also possible that COMPLETION_DATE is a datetime value with the DTDATE9. format attached to it.  Dates are stored as number of days, but datetime values are number of seconds.  To convert a datetime value to a date value use the DATEPART() function.